# MS Access query based on filtered query

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to use a query (query2) based on another query (query1).

On a form where both are displayed, I use VBA to add filters for query1. This works for query1, but query2 keeps using the unfiltered query1 as its source no matter what I try. Any suggestions welcome

Many thanks

Comment: Do you update your Query2 after you apply filter on Query1 ?

Comment: I'm using both queries on the main form, they are displayed as subforms. After applying the filter I've tried all methods to update query2 that I can think of, including requerying the subforms and the parent form, to no effect. Maybe I'm overlooking something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to approach this:
**Approach 1:** in Query2 set **Filter on Load** to 'Yes', then have your VBA add the filter clause to Query2 and re-run it.  So, if you want to filter Query1 based on column [foo] having the value "bar", your VBA would add this to the **Filter** property of Query2:

```
Query1.[foo] = "bar"
```

**Approach 2:** Parameterize Query 1 - have it use a WHERE clause that points to a control on the form (perhaps a hidden text control if you don't want users to see it). The structure of your VBA would then:
1. change the value of the hidden control
2. Requery Query 1, which will now use the new parameter value
3. Requery Query 2, which will be based on the values of Query 1 (which points to the hidden control).

Comment: One can also reference a public function defined in a module instead of a form control, in a query expression. I think this is what the asker is looking for - either referencing a form control's value, or a function. Of course, don't forget to requery the second subform if necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I'm not sure how to set "filter on load" for a query, but it is active for the form. For approach 1, the issue is that the filtered fields are not used in query 2. So I'm not sure how that should work. For approach 2, this is what I tried: I build the filter string in VBA, then set it as the filter property for the form that displays the query, and then display the form. From what I gather from your reply, this doesn't actually modify the query - only the display on the form - which fits my observation. Can you give an example for your solution? Again many thanks

Comment: Open the query in design mode, in the background right click and select 'Properties', then click on the background (not on a table) and you will have the properties for that query. You can set 'Filter on Load' there.

Comment: In Query1, I want to filter [foo] by having it equal "bar", so I put the value "bar" in MyTextBox on the form MyForm, and the WHERE clause for Query1 is now:  WHERE [foo]= [Forms]![MyForm]![MyTextBox]. Then if I requery Query1, it uses that WHERE clause to filter it, same thing if I requery Query2.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, your approach (number two) works. For my filter, I've built a string with multiple fields concatenated. So filter$ would be "([foo]=1 AND [bar]=2)". This works for the original goal of filtering the form (passing the string to the form filter). However, if I edit the query SQL and add "WHERE [Forms]![MyForm]![filter$]", that seems to do nothing. Is that supposed to work? I.e. can I build a multi-field WHERE clause and insert it into the query SQL as above?

Comment: You say: WHERE [Forms]![MyForm]![filter$] (which doesn't look like it would do anything), but my note was: WHERE [foo]= [Forms]![MyForm]![MyTextBox]

Comment: Yes, I see - and that works, thanks again. What I would like to do is make a string "[foo]= 1", put it on myform in the textbox [filter$] and then call that in the WHERE clause (using the example above). So the "WHERE [Forms]![MyForm]![filter$]" part would then become "WHERE [foo]=1". This for the purpose of concatenating multiple fields and filters in one string. Does that work?

Comment: The way to do that would be to form your SQL in a VBA query (where you put it together in VBA), but I don't think you can do what you want with saved queries in Access.